# Процедура с массивом

Tags: массивы, postgresql, procedure

Я передаю в процедуру массив строк, внутри мне надо запросами создать новый массив и вернуть его. Но как это сделать?

```
DROP FUNCTION selectnamedate(text[]);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selectnamedate(Names text[]) RETURNS text[] AS $$
DECLARE 
    name varchar;
    count text[];
BEGIN
 FOR name IN SELECT * FROM  Names
  LOOP  
    count  
  END LOOP;
 return count;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Вот где просто count я не могу найти как мне это сделать? Так же я вообще корректно объявляю функцию то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selectnamedate(names text[]) RETURNS text[] AS $$
DECLARE
    name text;
    res text ARRAY;
BEGIN
    FOR name IN SELECT * FROM unnest(names) LOOP -- Разбираем массив на элементы
        res := res || name; -- Добавляем элемент к результирующему массиву
    END LOOP;
    RETURN res;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: || конкатенация, а как прям добавить в массив то?

Comment: В блоке declare вы объявляете пустой массив, а потом на каждой иттерации добавляете к нему элемент. Можно, конечно, и так `array_append(res, name)`.

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста еще как доработать код, что бы вернуть несколько массивов (  RETURNS text[], text2[]).

Comment: Можно объявить OUT-параметр, если возвращаемых параметров немного, а можно возвращать record или table с полями типа text[].